# python 'string index out of range' error

Tags: python, indexing, syntax, range

I'm trying to code a word scrambler but when I try to append letters from my word, using index, I get the error 'String index out of range'. I have tried this without the 'input' but once I added it in I started getting problems.
my code is:

```
a = input('word ->')
b = []
count = 0
while count < 5:
    b.append(a[count])
    count +=1
print(b)
```

it would be great if someone could help. thanks

Comment: if you have word shorter than 5 letters then you can't get 5th letter - and you get your error. BTW: you can use `b = a[:5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you give input smaller than 5 a[count] is out of index. 
So try this one:

```
a = input('word ->')
b = []
count = 0
while count < len(a):
    b.append(a[count])
    count +=1
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but look at this:

```
word = input('word -> ')
b1 = []
# Iterate over letters in a word:
for letter in word:
    b1.append(letter)
print(b1)

b2 = []
# Use `enumerate` if you need to have an index:
for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    # `i` here is your `count` basically
    b2.append(letter)
print(b2)

# Make a list of letters using `list` constructor:
b3 = list(word)
print(b3)

assert b1 == b2 == b3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "count" will increase each loop until it reaches 5. If the string in the input is shorter than 5, you will get index error.